# Email multiple addresses from a composite element in a webform

Tags: webforms, 9

I need to email multiple addresses from a composite element in a webform. Using a Computed Twig element with this code:

```
{% for m in data.member_information %}
{{ m.email }}
{% endfor %}
```

The email addresses are listed line by line in Results.

```
test@test.com
random@random.com
```

I guess that means they're in an array, but I'm not sure. Here's the configuration of the composite element:

```
id: member_information
uuid: 591d262f-998d-4ade-8e40-56d8119592dd
status: true
label: 'Member Information'
elements: |
  first_name:
    '#type': textfield
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'First Name'
  middle_name:
    '#type': textfield
    '#title': 'Middle Name'
  last_name:
    '#type': textfield
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Last Name'
  phone:
    '#type': tel
    '#required': true
    '#title': Phone
  cell_phone:
    '#type': tel
    '#title': 'Cell Phone'
  email:
    '#type': email
    '#required': true
    '#title': Email
description: 'Group Nomination composite.'
langcode: en
dependencies: {  }
```

The configuration uses the [webform composite](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_composite) module.

In the handler, the email addresses need to be a comma separated list in the To email field, like this:

```
test@test.com,random@random.com
```

I've tried

```
{% for m in data.member_information %}
{{ m.email|join(',') }}
{% endfor %}
```

In Results, email addresses are still listed line by line.

How do I convert the line separated list to a comma separated string in the twig template?

Comment: How sure are you this is an array? It could be a line break. What is the configuration of the composite element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an array of email addresses, you have an array of composite field items.

So loop over the field items, build the array of emails

```
{% set emails = [] %}
{% for m in data.member_information %}
  {% set emails = emails|merge([m.email]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

and then output the joined array:

```
{{ emails|join(',') }}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.